# Combine 2 Textboxes into another Textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, autocomplete, textbox, expression

so i am still new to access, but am trying to auto populate a third textbox based on two other textboxes. i have one textbox asking for the DOB (mm/dd/yyyy) and the second text box for their last name.  so the third textbox would auto generate a combined value.  i know my basic equation would be

```
=Left([Last Name],3)+Right([DOB],7)
```

Example:  Birthday - 10/01/1978
          Last Name - Smith
          Result - Smi01/1978

any help would be great

Comment: That should be `TextBox3.Value = Left(TextBox1.Value, 3) & Right(TextBox2.Value, 7)`. If you prefer it more complicated, try this instead: `TextBox3.Value = UCase(Left(TextBox1.Value, 3)) & Format(CDate(TextBox2.Value), "mm/yyyy")`.

Comment: thank you so much for the help, but where would i add this, would it be under the control source, or under the on change event for the third textbox? the other issue i have is i then need to save this combination under a column person record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code you might paste to the code sheet of your user form.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    ' runs after every character typed
    SetTbx3 False
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
    ' runs when the focus leaves TextBox1
    SetTbx3 True
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    ' runs after every character typed
    SetTbx3 False
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_AfterUpdate()
    ' runs when the focus leaves TextBox2
    SetTbx3 True
End Sub

Private Sub SetTbx3(ByVal Complete As Boolean)

    If IsDate(TextBox2.Value) And (Complete = True) Then
        TextBox3.Value = UCase(Left(TextBox1.Value, 3)) & Format(CDate(TextBox2.Value), "mm/yyyy")
    Else
        TextBox3.Value = Left(TextBox1.Value, 3) & Right(TextBox2.Value, 7)
    End If
End Sub
```

There are 3 text boxes, TextBox1 (Name), TextBox2 (DOB) and TextBox3 (File name).
There are two event procedures for each of TextBox1 and TextBox2, `Change` and `AfterUpdate`. The Change event occurs when you type a character in the textbox. The Update event occurs when you move the cursor out of the text box after editing. This is for demonstration only. You may not need both.

All of these events call the Sub `SetTbx3` which requires one argument, "Complete" which, if True, signifies that the call came from the *AfterUpdate* event. `SetTbx3` will produce a different string for TextBox3 depending upon whether the arguments are complete or not but still provide a string based on the entered string, instead of the entered DOB date, if the date entered isn't recognized as a date.